# The improper integral $\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac1x+1}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to evaluate the integral 
$$\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac1x+1}\,dx.$$
Letting $u=\sqrt{\frac1x+1}$, the integral becomes
$$\int_{\sqrt 2}^\infty\frac{2u^2}{(u^2-1)^2}\,du,$$
which according to mathematica, equals $\sqrt2+\frac12\log(3+2\sqrt2)$. But using partial fractions, the antiderivative of $\frac{2u^2}{(u^2-1)^2}$ is
$$\int\frac{2u^2}{(u^2-1)^2}\,du=\frac{u}{1-u^2}+\frac12\log\Big(\frac2{1+u}-1\Big),$$
which I can't really make sense of as $u\to\infty$ to apply FTC (or when $u=\sqrt2$ for that matter). Is there an easier way to go about this integral? Or do we necessarily need to involve complex analysis because of log branches?

Comment: There is a mistake in your logarithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $x \ge 0$ an alternative substitution is let $x=u^2$.
Then
$$
2u\,du=dx
$$
and the integral becomes 
$$
2\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+u^2}\,du
$$
which probably looks much more familiar.
Interestingly this leads to a different form for the result
$$
\sqrt2+\log(\sqrt2+1)
$$
This is ok, this tells us, comparing the $\log$ terms
$$
\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt2+1
$$
which of course it is (square both sides).

Comment: This is cleaner, since indeed $\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{2}}=1+\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Real methods are sufficient here and you're on the right track. However, the argument of log should have $|\cdot|$, not $(\cdot)$. This gives
$$
\int\frac{2u^2}{(u^2-1)^2}\,du = \frac{u}{1-u^2}+\frac{1}{2}\log\left|\frac{2}{1+u}-1\right|
$$As $u\to \infty$, the first term goes to $0$ by L'Hopital and the second term goes to $\log|-1|=\log|1|=0$. At $u=\sqrt{2}$, we have
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1-2}+\frac{1}{2}\log\left|\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{2}}-1\right|=-\sqrt{2} + \frac{1}{2} \log|3-2\sqrt{2}|=-\sqrt{2} - \frac{1}{2} \log|3+2\sqrt{2}|
$$Negating this (subtracting this value of the antiderivative) gives the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

A by parts integration gives

$$\int u\frac{2u}{(u^2-1)^2}du=$$

$$\Bigl[-u\frac{1}{u^2-1}\Bigr]+\int \frac{1}{u^2-1}=$$

$$\frac{u}{1-u^2}+\frac 12\ln(1-\frac{2}{u+1})$$

the limit when $u \to +\infty$ is zero and at $ \sqrt{2} $ is
$\ln(\sqrt{2}-1)-\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, substitute $x=\sinh^2 t$ to integrate

$$\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac1x+1}\,dx
=\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}(1)} 2\cosh^2tdt \\
= \int_0^{\sinh^{-1}(1)} (1+\cosh 2t)dt= \sinh^{-1}(1)+\sqrt2$$

Note $ \sinh^{-1}(1)=\ln(1+\sqrt2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's calculate the whole antiderivative:

\begin{align}
\int_0^x \sqrt{1+\frac 1t}\,dt 
&= {\left[\begin{array}{ll} u = \sqrt{1+\frac 1t} & du= - \frac{dt}{2t^2\sqrt{1+\frac 1t}}\\ v = t & dv =dt\end{array} \right]} \\
&= \left.t\sqrt{1+\frac 1t}\right|_0^x+\int_0^x\frac{dt}{2t \sqrt {1+\frac 1t}}\\
&= x\sqrt{1+\frac 1x}+\int_0^x\frac{dt}{2\sqrt t\sqrt {1+\sqrt{t\,}^2}}= \left[ u = \sqrt t,\ du= \frac{dt}{2\sqrt t}\right]\\
&= x\sqrt{1+\frac 1x} + \int_0^{\sqrt x}\frac{du}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}\\
&= x\sqrt{1+\frac 1x}+\sinh^{-1}(\sqrt x)
\end{align}

This gives us $\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac1x+1}\,dx = \sqrt 2 + \sinh^{-1}(1) = \sqrt 2+\ln(1+\sqrt 2).$

Answer (score 0):

Letting $x=\cot^2 \theta$, then the integral is transformed into a simple integral as
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =-2 \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \csc ^3 \theta d \theta \\
& =-\frac{1}{2}[\cot \theta \csc \theta+\ln |\csc \theta+\cot \theta|]_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \\
& =\ln (1+\sqrt{2})+\sqrt{2}
\end{aligned}
$$